# carrot2 workbench and solr

Tags: solr, carrot2

I have a solr 7.3 installation on debian, and want to cluster results with carrot2 workbench 3.16.0.
I used carrot2 manual chapter 4.2.5 "clustering documents from a solr index" and:
- set "solr" as a source
- used default values in section medium
- set service url to: http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/select?wt=xml

I get results, but only a pure empty list without clustering

In  the clusters section (left side of the middle window of carrot2 workbench) I get:
Other Topics(nn), nothing else;
In the document section (right side of the middle window of carrot2 workbench) I get:
a empty list [0] until [nn];

whats goring wrong?

( service url: http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/select resulted in:
"com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: Content is not allowed in prolog" because the result was in json)

Comment: Do your document contain stored fields? Carrot2 can only operate on stored fields because it requires the original content of the document (Carrot2 performs its own tokenization, stemming etc.).

Comment: I'm new to solr - how do I find out this?

Comment: got it - field name had wrong spelling - was not default value, but can be extracted by having a look at http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/select?q=*